# Prevent line break before <sup> with only stylesheet CSS

Tags: css

I have this:

```html
<div>
  Yada yada yada.<sup>[1]</sup>
</div>
```

How do I prevent a line-break between "." and "[1]" ?
The big problem is that I cannot add anything in the HTML-document (because of hundreds of them), so I wonder if I can solve this by just adding something to the stylesheet. Right now I have in my stylesheet:

```
sup { white-space: nowrap;}
```

but that only prevents line-break to stuff within the sup-tag. I wonder if you can do something with sup::before. I've tried everthing i can think of...

Answer (score 0):

Make its width equal to 0 but pay attention as you may get some unexpected overflow.

```css
sup {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
}

div {
  border:1px solid;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Yada yada yada.<sup>[1]</sup>
</div>
```

Comment: Elegant solution that works for the last sentence in a paragraph, but just like you warned, when there's another sentence right after, the "[1]" overflows onto it.